# <cfmediaplayer> how to automatically play next track

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I've been working on creating a pop-up player for my site in which users can play a playlist of music that other users have uploaded to the site. However currently i'm having to manually click each track to play it, i was wondering if anyone has managed to create a `<cfmediaplayer>` which automatically plays the next song in the playlist. The way it knows which song to play currently is defined within a url variable that sends the track name the user clicks on, and then calls the database to see if it can find a match, then i use the source to output the location of the track i stored. Ill post code to give a much more clarified view of what i'm doing:

```
<cfquery datasource="#mydatabase#" name="getsongs">
    Select *
    From artists, songs
    Where artist_id = song_artistid
</cfquery>

<cfif IsDefined("URL.song")>
    <cfquery datasource="#mydatabase#" name="playsong">
        Select *
        From songs
        Where artist_id = song_artistid
        And song_name = '#URL.song#'
    </cfquery>
</cfif>

<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 800px;>
    <div style="width: 300px; float: left; overflow: scroll;">
        <cfoutput query="getartists">
            <a href="popup_player.cfm?song=#song_name#>#artist_name# - #song_name#</a>
        </cfoutput>
    </div>

    <cfif IsDefined("URL.song")>
        <div style="width: 500px; float: right;">
            <cfoutput>
                <cfmediaplayer name="song" source="artists/songs/#playsong.song_location#" autoplay="yes" height="500" width="500"></cfmediaplayer>
            </cfoutput>
        </div>
    </cfif>
</div>
```

As you can see, i have a scrolling div which lists all the songs that would be in the users playlist. By clicking on the song, it updates which track is played in the media player. I was wondering if there is anyway the next link could be automatically clicked when the song is finished and perhaps have a way that if a variable has been set to repeat the playlist when it reaches the last track it goes back to the first one again.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the reference guide for CFMEDIAPLAYER (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSE66DB0CD-E16D-49e7-AAEE-F51F9580554E.html). It has support for running JavaScript when the track ends. You could use that to automatically call the next track.

Comment: Cheers! Only question is, how could I write the JavaScript to check what the next track is in the playlist? I'm going to make it so when a user creates a playlist it creates a unique XML for them so wondering if i could create a playlist number for a track which the user sets making it easier in terms of parsing and selecting the next track.

Comment: If you know the tracks server side, you can output them as a JS variable that your code could use. See toScript(). Here is another blog post that could possibly help: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/8/27/Example-of-M3U-Support-for-CFMEDIAPLAYER

Comment: Yeah i can read through them server side rather than having to physically state them client side, with the toScript() function i should be able to carry across the value of the current row easily, allowing it to provide me with the right link.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a javascript when the song ends. 
Add to your current code:

```
 <cfmediaplayer onComplete=" YOUR_PLAY_NEXT_FUNCTION"  name="song"
 source="artists/songs/#playsong.song_location#" autoplay="yes"
 height="500" width="500"></cfmediaplayer>
```

**Added from the comments**

I haven´t tried it, but does this work for you?

```
var i = 0; // This should be the current song_no 
$("#button").on('click', function(){ 
    // Adds +1 to the current song number
    i++  
    // Create a variable using the standard url + the added song-number
    var curr_song = "artists/songs/#playsong.song_location#"+i;  
    // Changes the attribute to the new song-url 
    $('cfmediaplayer').attr("name",curr_song); 
});
```

Comment: My only issue is the javascript; how could i make it so that it knows which track to play next? One thing i have edited is i've added a playlistNo variable to the URL in which the value is the current row, so it knows where to jump to in the query. All i need is so that when it ends it knows to go to the link `<a href="popup-player.cfm?song=#song_name#&playlistNo=#currentrow# + 1>` how could this be done in javascript?

Comment: @Leeb I haven´t tried it, but does this work for you?

`var i = 0;  // This should be the current song_no
$("#button").on('click', function(){ 
  
 i++  // Adds  +1  to the current song number

var curr_song = "artists/songs/#playsong.song_location#"+i;  //  Create a variable using the standard url + the added song-number


$('cfmediaplayer').attr("name",curr_song);  // Changes the attribute to the new song-url


});`

Comment: This would be an okay solution if the JavaScript displayed the current row which the playlist is on. Unfortunately it doesn't, each song has it's own row based on where it is in the query, this is how i want to control track navigation by editing the current row and automatically moving to the next row in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've never used cfmediaplayer before but this pseudo code should get you where you need to be.

These are the resources I used.

1. [Dynamically starting and stopping a video using JavaScript and the CFMEDIAPLAYER tag in ColdFusion](http://coldfusionexamples.com/2010/11/23/dynamically-starting-and-stopping-a-video-using-javascript-and-the-cfmediaplayer-tag-in-coldfusion/)
2. [ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.setSource](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fda.html)
3. [cfmediaplayer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSE66DB0CD-E16D-49e7-AAEE-F51F9580554E.html)

---

```
<cfquery ...>
Select
   songUrl
from
   songs
</cfquery>
<!--- build your coldFusion array of song URLs --->
<cfset urlList = valueList(query.songURL)>
<cfset urlArray = listToArray(urlList)>

<script>
    <cfoutput>
    #toScript(urlArray)#
    var songIndex = #query.currentRow-1#; <!--- or url.currentRow, whatever you're using --->
    </cfoutput>
    startNext(){
        songIndex++;
        if(songIndex <= urlArray.length){                
            ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.setSource('mediaPlayerName', urlArray[songIndex]);
            ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.startPlay('mediaPlayerName');
        }
    }
</script>
```